# What is the purpose of datasync project in weblogic project?

Tags: weblogic

What is the purpose of datasync project in weblogic project?
What is *.evt, *.req, *.usr files?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation [on the docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/prodOps/datasync.html) about datasync. Basically it is a webapp used to copy data across from one weblogic server instance (actually from it's database) to another. Example - copying all the data from production to test instances.

*.evt, *.req, *.usr files are XML format files used in Weblogic Portal applications.

EVT files are event files which can be triggered at any user interaction with the Portal. This is mainly used for capturing user behaviour and firing any rules, an example is a 
campaign fired for specific users.

REQ files define the HttpRequest attributes

USR files define UserProfile attributes